# Entity Recognition in R error in openNLPdata

Tags: r, ggplot2, opennlp

This is my first attempt as using stackoverflow and I am also still very new to R, so I apologise if I screw up any formatting.

I am currently trying to get the entity recognition commands to work in the openNLP package. using their provided examples, however I am still getting an error. please see the code below

```
install.packages("rJava")
install.packages("openNLPmodels.en", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at")

library(NLP)
library(rJava)
library(openNLP)
library(openNLPdata)


s <- paste(c("Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a ",
             "nonexecutive director Nov. 29.\n",
             "Mr. Vinken is chairman of Elsevier N.V., ",
             "the Dutch publishing group."),
           collapse = "")
s <- as.String(s)

## Need sentence and word token annotations.
sent_token_annotator <- Maxent_Sent_Token_Annotator()
word_token_annotator <- Maxent_Word_Token_Annotator()
a2 <- annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
```

which returns as error:

````
Error: Can't find `geom` called 'Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29.
Mr. Vinken is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group.'
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred. ```

> rlang::last_error()
<error/rlang_error>
Can't find `geom` called 'Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29.
Mr. Vinken is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group.'
Backtrace:
 1. ggplot2::annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
 2. ggplot2::layer(...)
 3. ggplot2:::check_subclass(geom, "Geom", env = parent.frame())
Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see the full context.
> rlang::last_trace()
<error/rlang_error>
Can't find `geom` called 'Pierre Vinken, 61 years old, will join the board as a nonexecutive director Nov. 29.
Mr. Vinken is chairman of Elsevier N.V., the Dutch publishing group.'
Backtrace:
    x
 1. \-ggplot2::annotate(s, list(sent_token_annotator, word_token_annotator))
 2.   \-ggplot2::layer(...)
 3.     \-ggplot2:::check_subclass(geom, "Geom", env = parent.frame())
````

Please help me, I am so confused, as I ran it last thursday and it seemed to work, however now it doesnt. 
Thank you, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check your packages. It seems to be trying to use annotate() from ggplot2. I suspect you want it from NLP.  The last package loaded will mask functions from another. Try NLP::annotate() to explicitly specify.

Comment: This is going to sounds really dumb now, but how do you mark an a comment as the correct answer?

Comment: You can't. No need. Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me when I removed/unchecked ggplot2 from the library.

Comment: Please add necessary information with your answer. One liner are not helpful for readers. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer